# Chage the part of the URL using nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I m using nginx webserver. 
I want to change the url before it hits the server from

```
https://www.example.com/abc/contact-us
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/#/contact-us
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For a single URI redirection, an [exact match `location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [`return` statement](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) may be most efficient:

```
location = /abc/contact-us {
    return 301 /#/contact-us;
}
```

To redirect all URIs beginning with `/abc` use a `rewrite` directive:

```
location ^~ /abc/ {
    rewrite ^/abc(.*)$ /#$1 permanent;
}
```

The `location` block is largely redundant, but means `nginx` only looks at the regular expression when it needs to. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for more.

Comment: How to do that for all the routes passing through /abc.?